# What is the cultivar name of this golden-leaved juniperus?

Tags: identification, conifers

What is the cultivar name of this juniperus:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most likely Juniperus 'Old Gold' - it's listed as both Juniperus media 'Old Gold' and, more recently, as Juniperus x pfitzeriana 'Old Gold', but more generally known simply as Juniperus Old Gold, https://www.dobbies.com/products/plants/conifers/juniperus-x-pfitzeriana-old-gold/

Comment: What makes you think it is Old gold, and not Goden coast or Aurea?

Comment: see those spiky, longer shoots at the tips? That's typical of J. Old Gold, but not so typical of 'aurea'...  in  the end, though, its anybody's guess, they're all so similar in appearance

Comment: http://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-chinese-hybrid-juniper-cupressaceae-juniperus-x-media-pfitzeriana-7935233.html I can see such yellow spikes on almost all photos of Aurea.

Comment: In fact, some nurseries advertize 'yellow spikes' as a feature of juniperus Aurea.

Comment: there's a small difference in ultimate height and spread with the two you mention, so I'd make your choice based on that, if you want to buy one, as their appearance is  similar, although in my experience 'aurea' is not so colourfully yellow as Old Gold is in winter, for some reason, but maybe that's just the UK climate. Also possible many are mislabelled

Comment: The point of the question was to determine the exact cultivar.

Comment: I still think its what I said in my answer. You could always rummage around inside it to see if there's still a label somewhere...although as its relatively mature, even if there is, it may well have faded anyway. Or knock on the door and ask the owners...

Comment: It is a pubic space, and the city doesn't maintain public plant inventory.

Comment: @VividD If it's a public space, the local authorities must provide a copy of contract between them and the company that supplied the plants if you request this information. Look up L544/2001 or watch this 2-minute video that explains it and compare their answer with the one you got above: http://dialogsocial.gov.ro/2016/08/echipa-mcpdc-lanseaza-campania-dreptul-tau-de-a-sti/

Comment: @Alina, that is in theory. Local authorities work on completion of plant database, but in reality in many cases the origin is lost (supplier, and exact name as well).

Comment: They would anyway most probably track the plant on the photo as 'yellowish conifer beside the sidewalk'.

Comment: They have the obligation of providing a copy of the contract and its annexes, database or not database.